# android eclipse graphical layout bugs...do i have to restart

Tags: android, restart

Sometimes eclipse has problems with the graphical android layout such as not displaying the design or not displaying background images and other problems that don't disappear except when u restart eclipse.

The question is : do i have to restart eclipse every time when when i face these problems or is there an alternative way, because restarting eclipse has become very annoying for me and wastes a lot of my time.

Isn't there a way to some how refresh the layout or something?

Comment: You can already closed your xml to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @lopez.mikhael i have tried this before but it didn't work...i had to restart in the end

Comment: Ok, have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: @lopez.mikhael i will try next time i have this issue, but something tells me i have tried this also before

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to know what the exact problems you are having but it sounds like you may be able to clean your project to fix this when you have these problems

> Project --> Clean... --> Choose your project

Sometime Eclipse doesn't recognize your changes right away and is still working with the last build so you need to clean and rebuild to get rid of weird errors or layout issues